# помогите решить проблему css laravel

Tags: laravel

при компиляции npm run dev происходит вот эта ошибка.

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../img/fort.jpg' in 'W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\resources\css'
    at finishWithoutResolve (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:293:18)
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:362:15
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at processResult (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:690:19)
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:792:5
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:154:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\РОМАН\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-16T10_21_37_628Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\РОМАН\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-16T10_21_37_695Z-debug.log
```

причем если в файле /resources/css/app.css нету css кода то компилируется

css

```
*{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    list-style: none !important;
}

body{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(118, 185, 0);
}

a{
    color:rgb(156, 48, 48)
}

ul{
    padding-left: 0;
}

.container{
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 72px 21px rgba(73, 214, 19, 0.6);
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    color:rgb(156, 48, 48)
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler{
    border-color: rgb(235, 14, 14);
    border: 3px solid;
    color: rgba(252, 14, 14, 0.55);
}

.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show.nav-link{
    color: rgb(118, 185, 0);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: rgb(156, 48, 48);
}




.blog-header-logo{
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(19, 18, 18),

    0px 14px 10px rgba(91, 163, 24, 0.904),

    0px 24px 2px rgba(60, 187, 34, 0.1),
    0px 34px 30px rgba(17, 179, 17, 0.1);
    font-size: 40px;
}

.border-bottom{
    border-bottom-color: rgb(118, 185, 0) !important;
}


.green{
    color: rgb(118, 185, 0);
}

.red{
    color:rgb(156, 48, 48)
}

.link-secondary{
    color: rgb(118, 185, 0);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(236, 10, 10);
}

.link-secondary:hover{
    color: rgb(236, 10, 10);
}

.main__wrapper{
    position: relative;
}

.main__bg{
  max-width: 100%;
}

.main__text-bg{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 60%;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left:20%;

}

.box__main-text{
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(118, 185, 0),

                 0px 14px 10px rgba(91, 163, 24, 0.904),

                 0px 24px 2px rgba(60, 187, 34, 0.1),
                 0px 34px 30px rgba(17, 179, 17, 0.1);   
}

.shadow__nvidia{
        text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(110, 207, 30),
    
                     0px 14px 10px rgba(122, 207, 25, 0.904),
    
                     0px 24px 2px rgba(60, 187, 34, 0.1),
                     0px 34px 30px rgba(17, 179, 17, 0.1);
                     color: rgba(122, 207, 25, 0.904);
}

.shadow__amd{
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgb(218, 20, 20),

                 0px 14px 10px rgba(233, 39, 14, 0.904),

                 0px 24px 2px rgba(60, 187, 34, 0.1),
                 0px 34px 30px rgba(17, 179, 17, 0.1);
}

a.main__next{
    color:rgb(156, 48, 48);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);  
}

a.main__next:hover{
    color: rgb(100, 236, 10);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);  
}

.main__next{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.mini__card1{
    background-image: url(../img/fort.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper__img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.col-md-8{
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

.footer__text{
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width:432px) {
    .box__main-text{
        font-size:20px;
    }

    .shadow__nvidia{
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(110, 207, 30),
    
                     0px 2px 3px rgba(122, 207, 25, 0.904),
    
                     0px 2px 2px rgba(60, 187, 34, 0.1),
                     0px 2px 2px rgba(17, 179, 17, 0.1);
                     color: rgba(122, 207, 25, 0.904);
}

.shadow__amd{
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(218, 20, 20),

    0px 2px 3px rgba(233, 39, 14, 0.904),

                 0px 2px 2px rgba(60, 187, 34, 0.1),
                 0px 2px 2px rgba(17, 179, 17, 0.1);
    }
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    iframe{
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Было бы проще, если бы Вы выложили сам css и лог _2021-05-16T10_21_37_695Z-debug.log_

Answer (score 0):

Похоже не находит ***../img/fort.jpg***, проверьте пути

```
Error: Can't resolve '../img/fort.jpg' in 'W:\domains\da-kak-syka\syka\resources\css'
```

Названия конечно у Вас)

Comment: ну со вчерашнего вечера не могу починить  поэтому название такое)